# Placeholder Text With $scope.Array and HTML DIV

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to have default text (placeholder) displayed but I am unable to figure out how to place the text in but not include it as a drop down option.

HTML

```
    <div class="form-group">
        Upload new file to:
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDocumentType" ng-click="setDocumentType(selectedDocumentType)">
            <option ng-repeat="x in documentType" value="{{x.documentId}}">{{x.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

The Controller:

```
    $scope.documentType = [
        { name: "1003 Loan Application", documentId: "Form 1003"},
        { name: "Co Borrower 1003", documentId: "Application 2" },
        { name: "Credit Report", documentId: "Fico Score" },
        { name: "Drivers License", documentId: "DL0" },
        { name: "Executed Broker Package", documentId: "Executed Broker Package" },
        { name: "Insurance Binder", documentId: "Insurance Binder" },
        { name: "LOE-Handwritten", documentId: "Handwritten Letter" },
        { name: "Payoff Demand", documentId: "Payoff Demand" },
        { name: "Primary Profile", documentId: "Primary Profile" },
        { name: "Prelim", documentId: "Prelim" },
        { name: "Purchase Contract", documentId: "Purchase Contract" },
        { name: "Reserves", documentId: "Reserves" },
        { name: "Social Security Card", documentId: "SSC0" },
        { name: "Subject Profile", documentId: "Subject Profile"},
        { name: "Tax Certificate", documentId: "Tax Certificate" }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer,

I added a second  field. and used

```
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
```

Found the source at [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box/5859221#5859221)