# How to add placeholders inside div tag

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, placeholder

How can i add a placeholder for my dropdown inside a div tag? I have a dropdown which is being called out from another blade.php and i call that with

```
<div class="col-md-4 dropdowns">
    @include('applicants.for-deployment.fields_edit_rider_type')
</div>
```

Tried inserting

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Rider Type</option>
</select>
```

But it made my dropdown a mess. So i was wondering how can i insert a placeholder for my dropdown? Can i do it in the div tag?

**Update:**

[Output with my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHlVo.png)

[Output with select and option tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U5rH.png)

Comment: You can't modify the select dropdown? also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

Comment: I think op doesn't want to use a <select> because you cannot style it as good, at least that's what I read from "it made my dropdown a mess"

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or post the html that is output by your php

Comment: I'll update my post with screenshots! Thanks

Comment: Awesome  Thanks @Joshua

Comment: I have 3 dropdowns for this page but i have a script that hides unless an event change has been made. For this dropdown field i only have 2 options. I wanted to insert a placeholder to make this dropdown run smoothly. With my current code, i have to select the other option to show the next dropdown

Comment: It appears that your php is generating a drop down that isn’t in a select element. If you put the php inside of your select then change it to only output option tags, it will work as intended but might not be styled the way you want it.

Comment: @DanMullin i'll try that. thanks!

Comment: Remove the "hidden" part of your placeholder ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your php generate a list of option elements, then you could create the menu this way:

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Rider Type</option>
    @include('applicants.for-deployment.fields_edit_rider_type')
</select>
```

If the php generates a dropdown that isn’t in a select element you’ll have to come up with a custom solution to make your own placeholder

Answer (score 0):

change to this and bass you list selecte

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   @include('applicants.for-deployment.fields_edit_rider_type',['mylists' => $mylists,'selecte_id'=>$selecte_id])
</div>
```

in your blade dropdowns include

```
<select class="dropdowns">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Rider Type</option>
       @forelse($mylists as $mylist)
           <option value="{{ $mylist->id }}" {{ $selecte_id == $$mylist->id ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{ $value }}</option>
       @empty
              <option value="" disabled>No Data</option>
       @endforelse
    </select>
```