# How to show a fixed text next to the <option> inside <select> box

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a reactjs project (html + js + css available).

I have an HTML select object like this:

```css
.box {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<select class="box">
  <option value="1"><b>This text should be only visible inside box: </b>OPTION 1</option>
  <option value="2"><b>This text should be only visible inside box: </b>OPTION 2</option>
  <option value="3"><b>This text should be only visible inside box: </b>OPTION 3</option>
</select>
```

The objective is that the initial text (marked as: "This text should be only visible inside box: "), will only be on the  box, but not in the dropdown  menu. In the dropdown menu, should only appear three options: "OPTION 1", "OPTION 2" and "OPTION 3".

There is any way to do this?
I don't want an static text outside the box, I want the text **inside** the box.

Clarify concepts:

- Mobile devices have to identify it as a select (a div with custom dropdown, probably won't work).
- The text has to be visible after selecting the option. Imagine if the text is: "Your option is: ". At the beginning, it will show the first option (default), and after selecting another option, it will continue to show the initial text plus the selected option.

Comment: First, you don't end your `bold` tags. However, this isn't possible. Your best bet is to use a custom select plugin. Something that essentially converts a select to HTML using JS/CSS.

Comment: I've been thinking on create a "custom select" (basically, it can be done with a div box and a dropdown menu on it). The problem is that mobile devices would not understand it as a select.

Comment: Due to the various device and HTML Spec restrictions, you could rethink the requirement and maybe just have the text displayed ABOVE the drop down instead. I know how you want it to work but if you want it to work the same on mobile as a PC, you might need to adjust your requirements instead.

Comment: This is an option, for sure. Having a Custom select on desktop and then a basic select (without the text) on mobile.. But I still have a little hope that there is any way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: @SpykeRel04D Will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to put an invisible option for a placeholder.

```css
.box {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<select class="box" required>
  <option style="display:none" selected>Placeholder</option>
  <option value="1">OPTION 1</option>
  <option value="2">OPTION 2</option>
  <option value="3">OPTION 3</option>
</select>
```

The way this works is that the option element is only shown in the dropdown.
The text is shown in the box, but once you open it it cannot be seen.
The `required` means that you have to choose an option, and the placeholder is not an option since it does not have a `value`.

This might have a bad interaction with reader apps, although it acts fine with the arrow key select. (Opening and using arrow keys to change your selection.)

**Edit:**

I think I understand what you want.
However, I don't think there is a way to achieve it fully, but here is the best attempt so far.

```css
.box {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.select {
  border: none;
  padding: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="box">
  Your Selection is:
  <select class="select" required>
    <option style="display:none" selected>Placeholder</option>
    <option value="1">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="2">OPTION 2</option>
    <option value="3">OPTION 3</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: The problem is that after selecting an option, you won't see the text anymore. For example, if the text is: "The car color is: OPTION1". After selecting OPTION 1, you won't see the text anymore.

Comment: Then you can just add the same text to every real option. So replace `OPTION 1` with `Placeholder: OPTION 1`.

Comment: Hey Nick! But if I add the `Placeholder: ` prefix.. It will also be visible on the dropdown menu.