# Hide default value in selectbox in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created a codesandbox for the issue (https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-flower-k6cyl?file=/src/App.tsx)

How can we make the "AGE" text (first option) in select box not to be selected again? It should only be displayed when the component renders.

Is there a better way to do this as default option i.e. is string whereas the others are numbers?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check this question, I think the first answer may solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68798605/3070545

Answer (score 0):

You can add `defaultValue` to `SelectBox` and add `disabled` to first option.

```
<SelectBox
  defaultValue="myAgeLabel"
  id="age"
  value={selectedAge}
  onChange={changeAge}
>
  <option value="myAgeLabel" disabled>
    AGE
  </option>
  {AGES.map((age) => (
    <option key={age}>{age}</option>
  ))}
</SelectBox>
```

Answer inspired by [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5859221/1283124) and adopted to react.

Comment: It gives me this error, when I use it in my code: `Warning: Select elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled select element and remove one of these props.`

Comment: @newbie Here is the link to a codesanbox I've used https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-roman-7hx81?file=/src/App.tsx . Gives me no warning and no errors. Your warning indicates of improper usage for `value` or `onChange`. Can you share your full code with this warning?

Comment: It doesn't give any error in codesandbox but in actual React app it does.  The code is exactly the same as I copied it from the app to the codesandbox. Nothing is missing. The error is because you are using both `value` and `defaultValue`

Comment: Value is undefined by default. Are you sure you have `useState<number>();` ? I've just checked this behavior locally for react 17.0.2 and still had no errors\warnings.  Can you please copy your full code and create a github gist please?

Comment: It gives me this warning if I have some initial value for selectedAge, like so `useState<number>(1);`. But again, selectedAge is undefined by default.