# Add a disabled default option to select

Tags: reactjs

I want to have a default option in select saying "Select your option". But I want in to be disabled, which means that user should not be able to select it once he choose any value.

Here is an example:

```
function Select() {
    const [option, setOption] = useState();

    function handleOnChange(event) {
        setOption(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <select value={option} onChange={handleOnChange}>
            <option disabled>Select your option</option>
            {OPTIONS.map(value => (
                <option key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
    );
}
```

But if I'm adding a `disabled` prop to `option` it selects the first option which is not disabled. What should be adjusted to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a placeholder for a 'select' box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is to provide a default value to your `useState` and a value for your default option, so it gets selected. Like this:

```js
function Select() {
    const [option, setOption] = useState('');

    function handleOnChange(event) {
        setOption(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <select value={option} onChange={handleOnChange}>
            <option value='' disabled>Select your option</option>
            {OPTIONS.map(value => (
                <option key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I miss, to sync `useState` with default option

Comment: U r welcome, glad to help :)

Comment: @coder If you find an anwer satisfies the question, consider marking it as accepted. :)