# jQuery: Can I void !=0 for checking length?

Tags: jquery, null, return-value, string, string-length

I'm curious if the code

```
var $d = $('#person_data[document_type]');
if ($d.length != 0) {
  if ($d.val().length != 0 ) {...}
}
```

that was taken from SO [jQuery: checking if the value of a field is null (empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244565/jquery-checking-if-the-value-of-a-field-is-null-empty) is the best of the best?

Can I use

```
var $d = $('#person_data[document_type]');
if ($d.length) {
  if ($d.val().length) {...}
}
```

instead?

Which one is better?

Comment: So, what answer among answers is correct?:)

Comment: You can always just do `var $d = $(element).val();
if ($d && $d.length) { ... }` as that seems easier to me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/MhbVt/)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is fine, it relies on 0 being `falsey`.  It will spare a few extra bytes going over the wire which is always a good thing.  The two scripts will result in the same output, so I would take the more concise one.