# Jquery tmpl creating a or statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

```
{{if production_country != null || production_year != null}}
    <h3 class="heading">Details</h3>
    <p><b>${production_country} ${production_year}</b>, {{html roles}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

How can i create a OR statement. This doesnt works in my jquery template..

Comment: I have 2 variables 'production year' and the 'production country'. When one of this variables is empty, i don't wanna show the headline with the paragraph. How i do that in the if statement in my jquery template? It always show a error when im using the pipe '||'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
{{if production_country != null || production_year != null}}
```

Use:

```
{{if production_country !="" OR production_year !=""}}
```

I am unsure from your question if you need to determine the values of production_country and production_year. eg production_year.value!=""

see this question:

[jQuery: checking if the value of a field is null (empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244565/jquery-checking-if-the-value-of-a-field-is-null-empty)