# Why is $(…).val() == "" false when my input is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a class when nothing is inside of the `input` element, like in Google, when your search input is empty it won't show suggestions.

I have already tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$(".sc").keyup(function() {
  var x = $(this).val();
  $.post("search.php", { search: x }, function(checkSearch) {
    if (x == "") {
      $(".search").removeClass("searchOn");
      $(".search").html(checkSearch);
    } else {
      $(".search").html(checkSearch);
      $(".search").addClass("searchOn");
    }
  });
});
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `''` is not null.  It's an empty string.

Comment: x=='' won't catch null or undefined. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in

Comment: `$(".search").removeClass()("searchOn");` is also a logical error.  Remove the empty `()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: checking if the value of a field is null (empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244565/jquery-checking-if-the-value-of-a-field-is-null-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it
I should have use `===` instead of `==`

```
$(".sc").keyup(function ()
    {
       var x=$(this).val();
       $.post('search.php',{search:x},function (checkSearch)
       {
           if (x==='')
           {
               $(".search").removeClass("searchOn");
               $(".search").html(checkSearch);
           }
           else {
               $(".search").html(checkSearch);
               $(".search").addClass("searchOn");
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(x == '')` catches empty strings, not null.

Try using `if(!x)` instead (sees if x is null, undefined or empty string).

Comment: if he don't want to remove class when there is a empty string that code fails

Comment: @F.bernal the asker clearly states he wants to remove it when the input is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the input is null or undefined just compare with this values. An empty string (x = '') evaluates to true if you do !x. So if you only want to check then the value is null or undefined, do this.

```
$(".sc").keyup(function ()
     {
       const x=$(this).val();
       $.post('search.php',{search:x},function (checkSearch)
       {
           x === null || x === undefined 
            ? $(".search").removeClass("searchOn") 
            : $(".search").addClass("searchOn")

           $(".search").html(checkSearch);

       }
});
```